# find lines with 6 digits after 2 specific digits

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I need to create a regular expression that will show me lines that **contain** 94 or 95 or 96 or 97 or 99.

```
grep -P '(94|95|96|97|99)'
```

There's a good chance there's 6 or more numbers after those 2 digits, but there could be spaces between them, so I have to remove them.

```
sed 's/\(.\) /\1/g'
```

I then have to delete any mentions of 357, 00357 or +357

```
sed 's/\(357\|00357\|+357\)//g'
```

And the last thing to do, is make sure that each line only has 6 digits **after** the initial 2 mentioned above. So each line should **contain** a total of 8 digits, starting with 94 or 95 or 96 or 97 or 99. If there's more, or less than 8 numbers, that line is no use to me.

How can check if each line contains a number starting with 94 or 95 or 96 or 97 or 99, and has only 6 more digits after it, and show only those lines?

the input could be something like this

```
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   99 123456
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   9412 3456
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   95123456
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   456345 3453543654567
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   +357678423683
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   00357584903
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   +35 799 1276 45
2020-11-03  13:30   2020-11-03  14:30   97123456
```

and the expected output something like this

```
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   99123456
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   94123456
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   95123456
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   99127645
2020-11-03  13:30   2020-11-03  14:30   97123456
```

Answer (score 1):

I would match:

```
  Space
  9
  5 through 9
  0 or 1 Space
  6 digits
  a non-digit


grep -E ' 9[5-9] ?[0-9]{6}[^0-9]' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, you could do something like:

```
perl -lne 'if (/\t\K(?:(?:\+|00)? ?3 ?5 ?7 ?)?(9[4-9]( ?\d){6})\s*$/) {
           s{}{$1 =~ s/ //gr}e; print}' < file
```

Same with `sed` (assuming an implementation with extended regexp support with `-E`):

```
eval "$(printf 'NL="\n" TAB="\t"')"
LC_ALL=C sed -E "
  /$TAB((00|\+)?3 ?5 ?7 ?)?(9[4-9]( ?[0-9]){6})[[:space:]]*\$/!d
  s//$TAB\\$NL\3/;  # separate prefix and 8 digits
  h;                # save a copy
  s/.*\n//;         # extract 8 digits
  s/ //g;           # remove spaces among digits
  G;                # append saved copy and keep prefix and trimmed digits:
  s/(.*)\n(.*)\n.*/\2\1/" < file
```

Here, we assume the fields are TAB-separated like in your sample input and look for that number only when following a TAB to avoid false positives like in `+1 996 123456`.

Answer (score 1):

With awk

```
awk '{
    match($0,/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}/)
    last_part = substr($0,RLENGTH+1)

    gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"",last_part)
    gsub(/^(+|00)357/,"",last_part)

    if (last_part ~ /^9[45679]/ && length(last_part) == 8) {
        printf "%s%s\n", substr($0,1,RLENGTH), last_part
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   99123456
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   94123456
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   95123456
2020-11-03  13:00   2020-11-03  14:00   99127645
2020-11-03  13:30   2020-11-03  14:30   97123456
```

Explanation:

- `match()` matches the first 4 fields with their following spaces, After that, built-in variable `RLENGTH` holds the end of this first part. We could have splitted to fields, but I prefer not to split for this case, to keep initial allignment and to match easily the index of the digits area beginning, which is now `RLENGTH+1`.
- first `gsub()` removes all spaces in the digits area. We do this for convenience in two steps (for not bothering about any `+35 7` etc)
- second `gsub()` looks for the prefix (`+357`, `00357` or `357`) and removes it.
- finally, if the digits area starts with the prefix we want **and** the length is 8 characters, `printf` the new line.

Reference: [GNU awk string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)